# scipy.optimizeにおけるエラーの算出について

Tags: python, python3, scipy

こんにちは。
今私は実験で得たデータを解析するためにpython,scipyでフィッティングを行い、エラーの値も含めて算出したいと考えています。

元となるデータはxy平面にプロットした点のx,y座標のリスト

```
Epsilon_list = [e1, e2, e3, ... , e14]
G_list = [g1, g2, g3, ... , g14]
```

フィッティングに用いる関数はxを変数、M1,M2を定数として

```
def M_fitfunc(x, M1, M2):
    return (1 - 2*x)**(5/2) * (M1 + M2*x)
```

と設定しました。

実際にフィッティングした過程と結果は以下の通りです。M_para_optは最適解、M_covは共分散を示すようです。

```
M_para_opt, M_cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(M_fitfunc, Epsilon_list, G_list)

M_para_opt = array([ 133.45631973, -149.65607315])
M_cov = array([[   5.95002727,   93.90321683],
       [  93.90321683, 1498.93958525]])
```

最適解となるM1,M2を求めることには成功したようですが、M1,M2それぞれのエラーの値をどう求めればよいのかわかりません。scipyの公式ドキュメントによると、

```
np.sqrt(np.diag(M_cov))
```

つまり、M_covという２行２列のマトリックスの対角成分の平方根がM1,M2それぞれのエラーに相当するようですが、ここでわからない点がいくつかあります。

１．なぜ共分散がエラーの値として正しいのか
２．そもそも共分散(M_cov)が行列として表現されるのはなぜか
３．一般的に分散の平方根＝標準偏差だが、この行列の中の対角成分が共分散だとして、非対角成分は何を表しているのか

以上３点について、教えていただきたいと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一般に共分散は(非対角成分が等しい対称)行列として表現できます。
共分散を考えるということは沢山ある確率変数のうち、2変数を抜き出してその2つの確率変数間の相関とばらつきを考えることであり、それを列挙するための表現として行列は適切でしょう。(2の答え)
wikipedia - 分散共分散行列
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%86%E6%95%A3%E5%85%B1%E5%88%86%E6%95%A3%E8%A1%8C%E5%88%97
例えば確率変数x,yに対しては2×2の共分散行列が形成されます。
xとyの共分散をCov(x,y)と表現するとscipyが返す2×2行列は
[[Cov(M1,M1), Cov(M1,M2)]
 [Cov(M2,M1), Cov(M2,M2)]]
ここでM1同士の共分散Cov(M1,M1)は変数M1の分散を表します。
対角成分は結局のところM1とM2のそれぞれの**分散**になります。その平方根はそれぞれのパラメータの標準偏差です。エラーの定義にもよりますが、標準偏差はエラーの値として妥当ではないでしょうか？(1の答え)
非対角成分はM1とM2の**共分散**を表します。ここでCov(M1,M2)とCov(M2,M1)は当然等しいので、共分散行列は必ず対称行列になります。(3の答え)

Comment: なるほど、共分散がどういうものかということについて理解が足りなかったようです。